# touch and click event on same element and odd, browser-specific(?) problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, touch

https://jsfiddle.net/g4yt3e4o/

```
<button class="button">

</button>

html,body,div,button {margin:0;padding:0;border:0;background:transparent;outline:none;}

.button {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #0f0;
}
.button:after {
  position: absolute;
  display:block;
  content: '';
  background: #f00;
  top: 0;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  right:0;
  margin: auto;
  display:none;
}
.button:not(:active):after {
  display:block;
}


// find elements
var button = $("button")

// handle click and touch
button.on("click touchstart", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Because when you click it on desktop mode(use chrome for better understanding) it works. When you switch to mobile view(on chrome) it doesn't.

Simply saying - it doesn't work properly on mobile(with touch)...

Did anyone face this kind of problem?

Comment: Instead of `touchstart`, use `touch` event, and it will start to work.

Comment: @31piy are there any consequences when using `touch` instead of`touchstart`? I always seen `touchstart` used instead of `touch`...

Comment: I'm not a pro on this, otherwise I would have posted an answer with appropriate reason. I just tried `touch` and it started work; so I posted a comment.